# How to update XML file content with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, append, xelement

I have a XML file that contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<TokenToCardMapping>
  <pair key ="2313123124122512" value="3412412512512512"/>
  <pair key ="3414125121259723" value="3749327923749723"/>
</TokenToCardMapping>
```

I am looking for way to add a new **pair** element to the **TokenToCardMapping** descendants with XDocument or XElement.

I have the key and value as strings and I just want to add a new pair.

if my new key and value are: `111111111111 , 222222222222` I want to update the xml to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<TokenToCardMapping>
  <pair key ="2313123124122512" value="3412412512512512"/>
  <pair key ="3414125121259723" value="3749327923749723"/>
  <pair key ="111111111111" value="222222222222"/>
</TokenToCardMapping>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything or just expect someone to write it for you?

Comment: Look at XElement.Add() method and XDocument.Save() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy with `LINQ to XML`

```
// create new element
var newElement = new XElement("pair",
                 new XAttribute("key","111111111111"
                 new XAttribute("value","222222222222"));

// load the XML Document
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("path");

// Add new element to the root element
xDoc.Root.Add(newElement);

//And save the XML file
xDoc.Save("path")
```

**Note:** You need to add a reference to  `System.Xml.Linq.dll` from your project

And I would recommend you read the [`LINQ to XML tutorial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387087.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Where is the LINQ actually ?

Comment: @user2128702 `System.Xml.Linq`